Why doesn't Journald store kernel messages for as long as other messages are kept?
I have a computer running Fedora Workstation 40 and Systemd 255. For some reason kernel log messages are available in the Journal for much shorter time than other log messages.
user@host:~ $ journalctl -k | head
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: Linux version 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 (mockbuild@f1069ead281040288cd8d3761ad1265a) (gcc (GCC) 14.2.1 20240801 (Red Hat 14.2.1-1), GNU ld version 2.41-37.fc40) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 19 14:09:30 UTC 2024
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 root=UUID=800307e3-abdf-4cc6-a111-b068a8bb22a9 ro rootflags=subvol=root rd.luks.uuid=luks-5da2f27b-d221-4a68-a150-648d03962ac0 rhgb quiet
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000403fffff] reserved
Sep 07 22:15:28 host kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040400000-0x0000000075477fff] usable

user@host:~ $ journalctl | head
Aug 19 17:53:26 host systemd-journald[1079]: /var/log/journal/645eb9bfb5a942db9945b658805a08a5/user-1000.journal: Journal file uses a different sequence number ID, rotating.
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=user@42 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=user@1000 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1718]: USER_START pid=1718 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:xdm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_umask acct="gdm" exe="/usr/libexec/gdm-session-worker" hostname=host addr=? terminal=/dev/tty1 res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1675]: USER_START pid=1675 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd acct="th" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1675]: CRED_REFR pid=1675 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="th" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1679]: USER_START pid=1679 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd acct="th" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1679]: CRED_REFR pid=1679 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="th" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1799]: USER_ACCT pid=1799 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix acct="th" exe="/usr/bin/crontab" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 19 17:53:26 host audit[1799]: CRED_ACQ pid=1799 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="th" exe="/usr/bin/crontab" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'

Using journalctl command with sudo makes no difference.
According to journalctl --verify all Journal files are OK.
Journald config is using the default values:
user@host:~ $ systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/journald.conf
# /usr/lib/systemd/journald.conf
[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=10000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=no
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
#ReadKMsg=yes
#Audit=yes

Enough free disk space is available:
user@host:~ $ du -hs /var/log/journal/
465M    /var/log/journal/


user@host:~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0       237G   23G  212G  10% /
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G   14M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
efivarfs        154K   55K   95K  37% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs           3.1G  2.2M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       237G   23G  212G  10% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2  974M  353M  554M  39% /boot
tmpfs           7.7G  3.4M  7.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1  599M   20M  580M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   72K  1.6G   1% /run/user/0
tmpfs           1.6G  228K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000

What could be causing this and how can make kernel messages stay in Journal as long as other messages?

-k for journalctl implies -b -0, i.e., it shows only infos from the current boot. The messages are there; just not displayed. See man journalctl's information on how to pick the ranges that you get displayed.

journalctl -k -b all is what I was looking for.
